# Vertical peaks in single slit diffraction pattern

Tags: laser, diffraction, camera

I have the output from a single slit diffraction experiment using a HeNe laser (632.8nm), the diffraction grating is placed vertically so you expect to see only horizontal diffraction peaks in the “sinc squared” pattern.

However, there appear to be vertical peaks from the central peak. What is the cause of this? This vertical pattern also repeats near the edge of the image. Below is the image opened up in python to show the peaks clearly.

[image]

The diffraction pattern was captured on the CCD of a DSLR, so I imagine some reflection effects are occurring from the CCD glass?

Comment: Isn’t it due to the finite vertical size of your slit? After all, the vertical length scale is smaller in the diffraction pattern which corresponds to a larger length scale in real space.

Comment: @lpz oh right I see, so the finite vertical length of the slit acts as if it were a tall rectangular object interfering with the laser; producing 2D diffraction patterns?

Comment: That’s what I think. However, since I didn’t see your experimental apparatus, I cannot be sure

Comment: Like lpz said, what you are seeing is consistent with the product of the horizontal and vertical diffraction patterns. The former is determined by the slit width and the latter by the slit height. However, the finite slit height doesn't explain the odd and less regular vertical line across the right side of your image.

Comment: That does make sense. I suspect the lines on the right of the image are due to reflection. Those lines shifted left or right depending on the alignment of my laser with the CCD. I imagine an alignment that is not purely perpendicular causes the peaks to reflect off the rear surface of the CCD glass?

Comment: It's possible. If you adjust the alignment of the camera so that you are able to capture two such lines, that would support your guess. The second line would be due to a secondary reflection. It would be fainter and equally spaced from the first.